# Can I avoid a CONNECT request with cURL when using HTTPS and a proxy?

Tags: curl, https, proxy

**HTTP request**

When you make a HTTP cURL request with a proxy, you do:

```
curl -x http://myproxy:8888 http://github.com
```

cURL sends an HTTP request to the proxy myproxy:8888, which creates a new HTTP request to http://github.com

```
The request content is :
GET /
Host: myproxy:8888
Location: http://github.com
```

**HTTPS connect**

When you make an HTTPS cURL request with a proxy, you do:

```
curl -x http://myproxy:8888 https://github.com
```

cURL sends a CONNECT request to the proxy myproxy:8888, which creates a TCP tunnel between you and github. All SSL negociation are between you and github.

**HTTPS request**

I want to make an HTTPS cURL request with a proxy without CONNECT.
I want to create an HTTP request to the proxy for an HTTPS URL.

The request content will be:

```
GET /
Host: myproxy:8888
Location: **https**://github.com
```

**Is it possible ? How to do this ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible because CONNECT is what you use to do HTTPS through HTTP proxies. Handing over that control is giving up security and privacy, two things HTTPS is there in first place to provide.

I also [answered this very question](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2015-12/0010.html) just a few days ago slightly longer on the curl mailing list.

A follow-up question on the list was if we could imagine providing an option that would allow this way of doing HTTPS over a proxy in a future version, and yes we could do that provided that someone writes the code for said new option.

Comment: Thanks :) Someone ask me if it was possible with Scrapoxy (https://github.com/fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy/issues/3)